# isotope won't pushes itself out of tabs. other tabs get pushed to the bottom when opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QKgwyw

I am having trouble putting masonry inside of my tabs. only the filter part of isotope seems to sit inside the first tab. then when i open new tabs they all get pushed to the bottom under my isotope stuff.

also i added

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  $container.isotope('grid');
});
```

thinking it might help. found it in another post here. but it doesn't seem to do anything.

my end goal is to have three different isotopes. one in each tab. Should i do this with tabs as is? or is there a better method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by moving the opening and closing tags to encompass the whole lower part. the reason it was not working is because the tags were open inside one div and closed in a totally different div.